# Loading resource represented by android.R.attr.*

Tags: android, resources, attributes

I want to load resource that is located in android.R.attr class.

Next code failed to load resource with Resources$NotFoundException exception:

```
getResources().getString(android.R.attr.action); //action is a string resource
```

Also tried to load resource using:

```
getResources().obtainAttributes(android.R.attr.action)
```

No exception is thrown, but returned TypedArray array has nothing valuable inside it. At least I couldn't find anything that is connected to actual resource id or resource I'm interested in.

So, how to load resources represented by android.R.attr.* ids?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to load resource that is located in android.R.attr class.

I doubt that, since those are not resources. They are identifiers of parameters that can be supplied in various XML files (e.g., layout XML).

> //action is a string resource

`action` is not a string resource. If it were, it would be in `android.R.string`, not `android.R.attr`.

Comment: Ok, I was suspecting that I treated them wrong. But I was looking through android source code, and noticed activity_close_exit.xml animation resource. It is internal resource, but there is an android.R.attr.activityCloseEnterAnimation. I thought there is some connection between them.

Comment: @inazaruk: Copy that resource into your project, and you can use it.

Comment: I actually used reflection to get "internal" resource id. And using this id I could load resource successfully. I just thought there is a documented way for accessing some of those private resources.

Comment: @inazaruk: Do not do that. Internal resources are not part of the SDK. They may not exist on some devices. They may not exist on some versions of Android. They may change in the future. The *ID values* may change. Please copy the resource into your project, and you can use it.